# Why is it called "accredited investor" status with no accreditation process?

Tags: united-states, investing, financial-literacy

The word "accredited" has a pretty specific meaning: having successfully passed a formal process of certification.  But becoming an "accredited investor" doesn't appear to have any mechanism of accreditation; the definition (for an individual) is simply [someone with a high net worth or with a high income,](https://www.sec.gov/education/capitalraising/building-blocks/accredited-investor) with no actual *accreditation* mentioned anywhere.

Does anyone know where this seemingly-inconsistent term comes from?  For example, did there used to be an accreditation process that was discontinued in favor of the requirements we have today?

Comment: I don't think  your definition of accredited is correct. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accredit) has as its first definition: "to give official authorization to or approval of". In this case having sufficiently high net worth is sufficient to obtain official authorization or approval.

Answer (score 2):

There are more formal indicators in the "Professional Criteria" section of that page:

> - Investment professionals in good standing holding the general securities representative license (Series 7), the investment adviser representative license (Series 65), or the private securities offerings representative license (Series 82)
> - Directors, executive officers, or general partners (GP) of the company selling the securities (or of a GP of that company)
> - Any “family client” of a “family office” that qualifies as an accredited investor
> - For investments in a private fund, “knowledgeable employees” of the fund

"Accredited" does not mean *by definition* a formal process. It simply means "provided with credentials". That could be a formal or an informal process. Apparently the SEC chose to consider a high income an indicator of "credit" to be able to participate in certain transactions, but it is by no means the *only* way.

Comment: So is it required to meet *both* personal and professional criteria?  The impression I get from other sites is that you're an accredited investor if you meet any one criterion from any of the categories.

Comment: No I'm saying that high net worth/income is _one_ way for an individual to qualify; it's not the _only_ way.